# understanding how mysql joins work

Tags: php, mysql

i am having an bit of trouble understanding JOINS with mysql.

i have 3 tables.
gold_sended) user_id | sended

register) user_id | gold_swap_id

google_users) oauth_uid | portal_name

now what needs to be done is as follow.
first i need all the portal_names of google_users where oauth_id = the same as register.user_id

Next thing is i also need to check if the register.user_id = gold_sended.user_id

If the user_id from register is the same als gold_sended user_id then display

the portal name. If not then display nothing.

I never have worked with joins so i am an bit lost on how to do it propperly.

Ok its now solved.

```
SELECT
                            google_users.portal_name,
                            gold_sended.user_id,
                            gold_sended.date,
                            COUNT(gold_sended) as total_runs
                        FROM
                            register_gold_swap
                        LEFT JOIN google_users on register_gold_swap.user_id=google_users.oauth_uid
                        LEFT JOIN gold_sended on register_gold_swap.user_id=gold_sended.user_id
                        WHERE
                            register_gold_swap.gold_swap_id = "1"
                        AND register_gold_swap.status = "1"
                            GROUP BY google_users.portal_name
```

Is now outputting the correct data. Thank you all

Comment: How about a [visual example](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/), that also includes sample queries?

Comment: @PaulT. That is the problem i dont even know how to begin with it.

Comment: Begin with any basic book or tutorial

Answer (score 1):

```
    select 
      g.portal_name
    from
      gold_sended  as gs
   left join register as r 
      on g.oauth_id=r.user_id
   left join google_users as  g
      on gs.user_id=g.oauth_id
```

try this

Comment: That code generates an error. Unknown colom 'g.oauth_uid' in on clause

Comment: can you give me sql-dump?

Comment: Ok i got it now. i needed to change an few things for my self so i could understand it. Its fixed now. i only run into an different problem with my overall code. But will ask an new question for it